# Show Standard or Custom VF page as per profile in salesforce

Tags: salesforce, visualforce

Can we show custom VF page for few profiles and standard Edit page for other profile?
Currently my all profiles can see custom VF page.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create two record types and assign records layout based on profiles.

Answer (score 0):

i have solution

1. in visualforce page, create two section
   (1- edit section, 2- no permission message section)
2. use rendered ="{!if( ~~~ ,true, false)} for each two section
     ( ~~~ = $user.profile = [profile id]  )

   - use like 'if( ~~~ , if( ~~~, true, false),false)'  for many profile

Then depending on profile, you will get a different page.

Answer (score 0):

If you have overridden the standard edit action with Visualforce/Aura/LWC - this is it. It's all or nothing, not profile-specific.
You could have 2 layouts and on one display custom edit button, on another - standard one? This can quickly grow unmaintainable if you need more differences than just the button. If you currently have 5 layouts - worst case in new world you'd need 10, mess.

What you can do is (ab)use the `<apex:page>`'s "action" parameter. Write a method that would be checking the user's profile and if it's one of special ones - redirect. In fact it doesn't even have to be an apex function but if you do it in pure visualforce it'll look bit messy and you can't unit test it so what if it breaks in future.

Something like

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" action="{!IF($User.ProfileId != '...', URLFOR($Action.Account.edit, account.id, null, true),'')}" >
...
... rest of your page
...
</apex:page>
```

You'll probably have to modify it, pass more parameters. Or maybe you'll figure out how to take full current url from $CurrentPage and just slap `&nooverride=1` at it.

Combine stuff like

- https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/51151/vf-controller-redirect-to-another-page
- https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F000000096HtIAI
- https://blog.jeffdouglas.com/2008/11/14/redirecting-users-to-different-visualforce-pages/

with knowledge about URLFOR and PageReference class and update your question with code sample if you're still stuck.